# How can I install CWM on Android-x86?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

I wonder how can I install CWM/TWRP to Android-x86 for rooting, flashing, debugging etc. ? Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Android-x86 comes rooted. What debugging are you trying? USB Debugging is available and works well.

Comment: I am using a VM - Also I need to flash ZIPs too.